# why to get mouse out event in legend in highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

https://plnkr.co/edit/JCOQa1vdqU9KBusqlOlL?p=preview
Hi
I make a simple demo of donut chart .I want to get mouseover event and mouseout event on legends.I am able to get mouseover event on donut slices.It is working fine.I want same functionality on legends.I get mouseover event on legend but my mouseout event not fired why ?

```
   $(chart.series[1].data).each(function(i, point) {
                $(point.legendItem.element).hover(function () {
                    // on over
                    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[1].data.length; i++) {

                        chart.series[1].data[i].update({
                            color: i === point.index ? point.options.origColor:'grey'
                        }, false, false);
                    }
                    chart.series[1].chart.redraw();
                }, function () {
                    // on mouseout
                    alert('--')
                });
            });
```

on mouse out I want to move it on original/same state

Comment: If you comment out `chart.series[1].chart.redraw();` it will fire the `handlerOut ` alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get mouseover event on legend but my mouseout event not fired why ?

As [Ryan Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115895/ryan-gill) already pointed out, the problem is in `chart.redraw()`. I don't know exactly how mouse events work in this case. It looks like mouse over event is lost when legend div is updated.

But if I understand correctly that your "real" problem is reseting data selection on legend mouse leave event, here is a workaround:

I added `chart.legend.options.mouseOverLegend = true;` in your hover function and removed mouse leave event listener:

```
$(chart.series[1].data).each(function(i, point) {
    $(point.legendItem.element).hover(function () {
        // on over
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[1].data.length; i++) {

            chart.series[1].data[i].update({
                                               color: i === point.index ? point.options.origColor:'grey'
                                           }, false, false);
        }
        chart.series[1].chart.redraw();
        chart.legend.options.mouseOverLegend = true;
    });
});
```

And than I added mouse over event listener on svg element. `mouseOverLegend` is used that series data is iterated only once:

```
$('#container').find('svg').on('mouseover',function() {
    var isMouseOverLegend = chart.legend.options.mouseOverLegend === true;
    if (isMouseOverLegend) {
        var isDirty = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[1].data.length; i++) {
            if (chart.series[1].data[i].color == 'grey') {
                isDirty = true;
                chart.series[1].data[i].update({
                                                   color: chart.series[1].data[i].options.origColor
                                               }, false, false);
            }
        }
        chart.legend.options.mouseOverLegend = false;
        if (isDirty) {
            chart.redraw();
        }
    }
});
```